# Date time not working correct on mac os -3 hours

Tags: javascript, macos

I have a problem that the date of my website is being displayed differently on windows and mac os.
I'm getting this date from the server, "2020-06-15T11: 17: 20", and I'm converting this string to a date object in JS as follows:

```
let dateTime = new Date('2020-06-15T11:17:20').getTime();
```

On Windows with google chrome it works just fine, but on mac os that date is 3 hours less, "2020-06-15T08:17:20".

Does anyone have any idea why this behavior is happening on mac os?

Comment: `dateTime` in your example is a number, how are you viewing the date where it comes out like that?

Comment: yes, is number!

Comment: But where are you seeing "2020-06-15T08:17:20"? How are you getting that string?

Comment: Whenever the time is a few hours off, it's always a timezone issue.

Comment: https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-date.parse *If the String conforms to the Date Time String Format [...] When the UTC offset representation is absent  [...] date-time forms are interpreted as a local time.*

Comment: @JohnMontgomery, this value comes from the server

Comment: @Barmar, can you explain better, this problem?

Comment: I think your Mac is set to a different time zone than the Windows machine. They're 3 hours different.